# kdb/q How can I save a Dictionary?

Tags: csv, dictionary, output, export-to-csv, kdb

I have a dictionary and I'm trying to save using kdb/q. To save my dictionary, I try the same method as I would a table:

```
save `output.csv
```

However, my output dictionary (type 99h) gives me an error:

```
q))save `output.csv
   'output
   [4]  save `output.csv
        ^
```

I think this is because the notation only works for tables and not dictionaries. Can anyone help me with how to do this, or if it isn't possible, how I can change a dictionary to be a table?

Here is what my dictionary looks like:

output -> type 99

[image: an example of the dictionary]

Output using `:out.csv set output

[image: `:out.csv set output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. `save` is flexible enough to write a keyed table to csv. https://code.kx.com/q/ref/save/

```
q)output:([Name:`Tim`Bob`Ant;Time:02:20 01:12 03:30;ID:`9h`8a`2w]Score:100 212 998;Comment:("";"Late";"Over"))
q)type output
99h
q)save`output.csv
`:output.csv
q)read0`:output.csv
"Name,Time,ID,Score,Comment"
"Tim,02:20,9h,100,"
"Bob,01:12,8a,212,Late"
"Ant,03:30,2w,998,Over"
```

The error message you've pasted would indicate that `output` doesn't exist in your current context. Are you perhaps trying to save a local table rather than a global?

```
q){output2:([Name:`Tim`Bob`Ant;Time:02:20 01:12 03:30;ID:`9h`8a`2w]Score:100 212 998;Comment:("";"Late";"Over"));save`output2.csv}[]
'output2
```

Comment: Hello, yes I am trying to save a local variable within a function.
My function looks something like this:
fGetOutput:{[inp_tbl]
    
    ...some stuff...
    
output: ...
save `output.csv}

Comment: `save` is only for writing globals. To save a table local to your function, you can use `0:` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/, something like `:path/to/file.csv 0: csv 0: output

Answer (score 2):

Use `set` to write a binary file:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/get/#set

```
q)`:file set `a`b!1 2
`:file

q)get `:file
a| 1
b| 2
```

Note: File paths must be `hsym` .i.e a symbol starting with `:`

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/hsym/

Your object is a keyed table which is a special type of dictionary.

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/faq/#keyed-tables

You can unkey a table using `0!`

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enkey/#unkey

```
q)t:`a`b xkey ([] a:1 2;b:4 5;c:5 6)
q)type t
99h
q)t
a b| c
---| -
1 4| 5
2 5| 6
q)0!t
a b c
-----
1 4 5
2 5 6
q)type 0!t
98h
```

A dictionary of uniform length lists can be converted to a table also using `flip`

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/flip/

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but it gave me some really weird output. I can't paste the screenshot in the comments, so I added it as an edit to my post above

Comment: That is because it is a binary file. For csv use `save` or `0:` https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#1143-preparing-text